# WSO2 Identity Server SMS OTP step then Email OTP step after Username and Password Authentication step

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

i have issue with enabling SMS OTP Step then Email OTP step after username and password step.

- first i configured SMS OTP and Email OTP identity providers.
- then i change local and outbound authentication configuration in service provider configuration. as per attached image

[service provider configuration] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WREK3.png)

after that try to login in service

first system displays username and password form then SMS OTP form then blank page appear with https://localhost:9443/commonauth URL although i received email with OTP, as per attached images.

[Step 1] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6g21.png)

[step 2] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A8ZN.png)

[Step 3] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLZWX.png)

i try to change order of steps to be username and password step then email OTP then SMS OTP, the result is system ask user about username and password then email OTP then user log in successfully without SMS OTP step!!!

please advise how to login user after three mentioned steps (basic > SMS OTP > Email OTP)

Comment: could you please mention the IS version that you use?

Comment: Also mention whether you are seeing any errors in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The initial issue mentioned in the question, hanging on commonauth endpoint if basic > SMS OTP > Email OTP steps configured scenario is already reported in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/15364.

That issue is fixed by https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-email-otp/pull/151.

You can patch this change to your WSO2 IS server and try out the flow.
Refer to this:https://tharika.medium.com/how-to-apply-java-code-changes-to-wso2-server-on-the-go-caba252370 for more information on applying a patch.